# How and in what language can you create this very little script so it works for Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, python, windows, script, software-development

I have bought a Raspberry Pi 3 but I cannot run .exe on it (i got a self made script on Windows but it doesn't work for Raspberry).

What I want is open browser, press f5 button, loop

Can you please tell me how to code that on Raspberry Pi 3 OS Raspbian and what language?

That's all I need to know and if I know that I could do many other different things on my own. But please help me, I have checked so many different sites but nothing could give me the basics, searching desperately for 2 weeks now with no result so I hope you can help me with this?

Or you can tell me a way to run .exe on raspberry pi 3 raspbian os as alternative?

So if you answer please tell me the language and if you can please write a short script as example so I know some little basics.

Comment: you may want to look at xdtool

Comment: If the answers and suggestions here do not work for you, you should consider breaking the task into discrete parts.  This probably does not require more than a few lines of shell, but asking people to write it for you is inappropriate.  However, e.g., "How can I open chromium from a shell script?" is fine.  Or whatever language you like, but shell is probably the most straight forward here.

Comment: I have a script in mind and I consciously didn't ask it here because I want do it alone and because it's not small. But I need to know what to use and if possible some little basics because on the internet I didn't find anything helpful searching for several weeks. They explain like i'm a pro at linux and used it always. How can a newbie like me understand that..? No way.

Comment: But I will look into it maybe there is a good tutorial too ^^

Comment: Install node and PhantomJS - do whatever you want with the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .exe programs on Raspbian using Mono. Install it by typing `apt-get install mono-complete` into the console.

After the installation is done, you should be able to run your program with `mono (PROGRAMNAME).exe`

Alternatively, write your program in C or C++ and compile it using `gcc (FILENAME).c` or `g++ (FILENAME).cpp`

Comment: If I read the question correctly, OP created a script (pure guess: AutoHotKey) and converted it to .exe. I'm not sure how Mono would help here (even more so: how it would be able to control the graphical interface of a native X Windows application). Writing C or C++ code to open a browser and make it refresh a page seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: That's right I used AutoHotkey. You know if there is a (free) way to run this on rapsberry? I don't understand how these languages like python / xdtool are supposed to work when they can only do things like output in the command. I want some output in browser, as example that the script clicks to this question i asked, and writes a command here, just as example.